# SSH equivalent of PuTTY remote forwarding?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, putty

I need help with finding the `ssh` equivalent of PuTTY remote forwarding. The scenario is that if I use PuTTY remote forwarding like this

[image: Putty remote forwarding]

I am able to access `localhost:3030` by connecting to `remote:3000`.
But if I try to accomplish the same using `ssh` command like so

[image: SSH Command]

```
ssh -R 3000:localhost:3030 REMOTE_IP
```

I get an empty response when I try to access my server using Chrome:

[image: Chrome Error message]

Comment: Unclear.  You’re in PuTTY, then at the command prompt, then complaining chrome didn’t get a response....

Comment: Try running `ssh` with the `-vvv` flag. This will make ssh print a lot of debugging info. Then try to connect to the remote port as before. If your remote connection attempt is successfully tunneled back to the local ssh process, ssh should print some debug info about its attempt to handle the tunnel request.

Comment: @Tyson I'm saying that I'm able to access any port if i expose it via putty but if i try to replicate the same behavior by running the equivalent SSH command it gives me empty response. So whats the issue.. are the commands somehow different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle I finally figured it out. The issue was kinda strange because 
I was doing 
ssh -R 3030:localhost:3030
but all I needed to do was 
ssh -R 3030:127.0.0.1:3030
and it was able to connect properly

Answer (score 2):

-R does it in reverse, it puts a 3000 port on the remote side that connects to 3030 locall.

`-L` is what you want;

```
ssh -L 3000:localhost:3030 REMOTE_IP
```

ssh also has a -D option if you want to configure Chrome to use this port and then all connections are resolved from the remote server as the origin of the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want exactly that. I want the remote 3000 to connect to 3030 but the issue im having is that if i do it with putty it works but if i do it with ssh it gives an empty response so that's what im asking what if i dont want putty what if i just want to do it with plain old ssh. how can I achieve that

Comment: Ok. Got it. Try a) `ssh -R REMOTE_IP:3000:localhost:3030 REMOTE_IP` to ensure that the remote end is listening on the public interface on the remote side. Look at `ss -lntp` on the remote end. Try `wget REMOTE_IP:3000` in your ssh connection to see if you get a response. If that fails try `ssh -vv` as previously mentioned.